# Weird output during JVM application execution in Eclipse - how to debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I've encountered weird Eclipse console output during my application execution. I'm almost 100% sure that it's my application's fault, but I couldn't find any information on how such output should be interpreted. After printing those characters, Eclipse freezes.

Screenshot [here](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/8125/screenshotbi.png)

My bet is problem with thread synchronisation, but how can I be sure what causes such behavior?

Comment: You might want to provide at least the faintest clue as to what the program is doing around the time this happens. All anybody has to go on at this point is a screenshot of some boxes...

Comment: It communicates via telnet with some hardware. Pure telnet communication works fine, but problem occurs after adding some Timers, used for timeout handling etc. That lead me to conclusion that problem is related with threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting log printout messages before/after relevant code parts to trace where the problem lies. If it is related to threads, it may be difficult or impossible to reproduce in a debugger, since most concurrency bugs depend on subtle timing coincidences between the different threads.